# Connecting a point in a Map to a legend by Line in R

Tags: r, maps, sankey-diagram

Is this graph available in R? i searched alot of how connecting points with legends like making  a line between public agency and planned point in map but i couldn't find a solution for that .

[image]

I found something similar called Sankey map but there's no function allowing me to plot it and heard it makes by illustrator.

I tried to get a map and put text on it then draw points an connect text with points though lines, but it was so ugly because of line shape, and i've to do alot of manual work to finish the graph i want and it's always update so it's not good to do manual work .

So Help please.

[image]

Comment: you need to add more information if people should help you: what are your spacial data? what kind of map you want to plot? how should the lines look like which what you want to connect the points (this is to ugly, is not a good description what you want ;)